# how can I fix my error with this import function

Tags: contract-development, remix, blockchain, chainlink

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity  ^0.8.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract ExtraStorage is SimpleStorage {
    // + 5 
    // override
    // virtual and override 
    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public override{
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber +5 ;

 }    
 
}
```

// the error in question is: "Error: not found contracts/SimpleStorage.sol "

I've imported SimpleStorage previously into my StorageFactory contract but I'm having difficulties importing with this with this newer contract.

Comment: The format of the import statement looks fine, assuming that the SimpleStorage.sol is in the same directory, and the capitalization is consistent.  Dont know what's going on with the contract and function definitions -- if that's really the way its written, it could be contributing to the problem.  You can't necessarily trust the compile messages, sometimes they don't fully tell you what's causing theproblem.

Comment: thanks a ton for the help! I  ended up realizing that my ExtraStorage contract was inside of a different contract folder that's why it couldn't find the SimpleStorage contract when I called to import it.  lol I'm coming to learn that it's the little details that count.